# jQuery autocomplete go to url on click

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

**How would I go to a url on click from the returned results?**

www.mydomain.com/search?q=***data-attribute-here***

```
   $(function(){
      var currencies = [
        { value: 'Afghan afghani', data: 'AFN' },
        { value: 'Albanian lek', data: 'ALL' },
        { value: 'Algerian dinar', data: 'DZD' },
        { value: 'European euro', data: 'EUR' },
        { value: 'Angolan kwanza', data: 'AOA' },
        { value: 'East Caribbean dollar', data: 'XCD' },
        { value: 'Argentine peso', data: 'ARS' },
      ];

      $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
        lookup: currencies,
        minLength: 3,
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
          var thehtml = '<strong>Currency Name:</strong> ' + suggestion.value + ' <br> <strong>Symbol:</strong> ' + suggestion.data;
          $('#outputcontent').html(thehtml);
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $("#autocomplete").bind("change",function(){
         document.location.href = "www.mydomain.com/search?q=" + $(this).val()
    })
```